# Accessing the logic values of a TikZ coordinate

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, coordinates

In TikZ accessing the coordinate values of a node can be done using the `let` syntax of the `calc` library or using the PGF command `\pgfpointanchor`. However, this values are dimensions/lengths in points and not the values of the used coordinate system. For example, I like to label certain points and nodes in the graph with their logical coordinate values, e.g. in a standard `tikzpicture`, i.e. with `x=1cm,y=1cm` in effect, a point at `(1,2)` should be labeled with `(1,2)` not with `(28.4527pt,56.9055pt)`. The nodes are not positioned manually, but using the various relative positioning techniques of TikZ, so I don't know the coordinates myself. This is about normal 2-D XY coordinate systems with orthogonal X and Y axes.

The way I do this at the moment is to get the length of a unit vector in points and divide the coordinate lengths with it to calculate the corresponding value of the used coordinate system. This works OK, but of course results in rounding errors, e.g. 1.9998 instead of 2. I then use the `\num` function of `siunitx` to round the numbers to a fitting number of digits.

*My question:* Is there a better way to achieve this for arbitrary TikZ coordinates?
I mean something more user-friendly and maybe provided by TikZ itself (I didn't found anything in the manual).
Especially: Can TikZ/PGF round the number as well without an extra package?
A guess TikZ converts coordinates always quickly to length, so that rounding errors are unavoidable (except using `x=1pt,y=1pt` maybe).

Here my proof-of-concept solution. It is very inflexible at the moment because it only works for nodes.

```
\documentclass[png]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage[round-mode=places]{siunitx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\xcoord[2][center]{{%
    \pgfpointxy{1}{1}%
    \@tempdima=\pgf@x
    \pgfpointanchor{#2}{#1}%
    \@tempdimb=\pgf@x
    \pgfmathparse{\@tempdimb/\@tempdima}%
    \num{\pgfmathresult}%
}}
\newcommand\ycoord[2][center]{{%
    \pgfpointxy{1}{1}%
    \@tempdima=\pgf@y
    \pgfpointanchor{#2}{#1}%
    \@tempdimb=\pgf@y
    \pgfmathparse{\@tempdimb/\@tempdima}%
    \num{\pgfmathresult}%
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [help lines] (0,0) grid [step=1] (2,4);
    \draw [name path=A] (0,0) -- (2,4);
    \draw [name path=B] (2,0) -- (0,4);
    \draw [name intersections={of=A and B}]
        (intersection-1)
        node [right] {(\xcoord{intersection-1},\ycoord{intersection-1})}
        circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: What other things (other than nodes) would you want to use the function for? I can't think of a way to refer to a coordinate other than through a node.

Comment: @Jake: Any numeric `(x,y)` coordinate or node anchor points for example. Here *coordinate* doesn't need to be a `\coordinate`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

PGF has the `\pgfmathprintnumber` macro that allows you to print and format numbers, including rounding. To round to two decimal digits, you would use `\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=2]{\pgfmathresult}`, for example.

The unit vectors are stored in `\pgf@xx` (for the x-component of the x unit vector) and `\pgf@yy` (the y-component of the y unit vector). So your function could be shortened to

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\xcoord[2][center]{{%
    \pgfpointanchor{#2}{#1}%
    \pgfmathparse{\pgf@x/\pgf@xx}%
    \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}%
}}
\newcommand\ycoord[2][center]{{%
    \pgfpointanchor{#2}{#1}%
    \pgfmathparse{\pgf@y/\pgf@yy}%
    \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}%
}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for to solve the rounding part of my question. I gives me `(1,2)` in the above example.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question to include `\pgf@xx` and `\pgf@yy`. They make my live simpler. I saw there are also `\pgf@xy` and `\pgf@yx`, but there are zero; for orthogonal coordinate systems I guess.

Comment: Are you sure that it is safe to use `\pgf@x` and `\pgf@y` inside `\pgfmathparse{...}`.

Comment: @Martin: I don't see why it wouldn't be. If the `\pgfmathparse` follows the `\pgfpointanchor` directly, `\pgf@x` should hold the correct value. It's used in a `\pgfmathparse` expression in `tikzlibrarygraphs.code.tex`, though there it is preceded by `\the`.

Comment: @Jake: It should be save as long `\pgfmathparse` doesn't change it before reading it. I had a look in `tikzlibrarygraphs.code.tex` and can't find any use of it in the current version (2.10).

Comment: @Martin: I'm using the development version of PGF. It's in lines 1638 and 1643 of v 1.17 2010/12/17 of `tikzlibrarygraphs.code.tex`: `\pgfmathparse{#2+\the\pgf@x}`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the accept this answer. I wanted to wait a day to allow for alternative answers...

Comment: @Martin: No worries! I wouldn't mind if you unaccept it and maybe edit your question to include the requirement of a solution working with arbitrary coordinates more explicitly.

Comment: Just a note: this needs slightly more complicated math when the `x` and `y` vectors aren't horizontal/vertical.

Comment: @jake I used your functions, until I came to a scaled tikzpicture and then it was off. I now have added a factor for the scaling, but I am looking for a method to make it universal. That would mean the xcoord/ycoord would take the picture's scaling into account through a tikz/pgf variable.

Comment: @Louis: Please do not use answer posts to address other users. I converted your post to a comment. Unfortunately, new users with a reputation lower than 50rep are not allowed to post comments everywhere, just to own questions and their answers. Please feel free to ask any follow-up questions as new question ("Ask Question" button above) and link back to this answer from their.

Answer (score 10):

Here is another method to extract coordinate values from a node or an anchor. Its advantage is to provide these values ​​taking account of the current origin.

```
\makeatletter
\def\extractcoord#1#2#3{
  \path let \p1=(#3) in \pgfextra{
    \pgfmathsetmacro#1{\x{1}/\pgf@xx}
    \pgfmathsetmacro#2{\y{1}/\pgf@yy}
    \xdef#1{#1} \xdef#2{#2}
  };
}
\makeatother
```

Example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\makeatletter
\def\extractcoord#1#2#3{
  \path let \p1=(#3) in \pgfextra{
    \pgfmathsetmacro#1{\x{1}/\pgf@xx}
    \pgfmathsetmacro#2{\y{1}/\pgf@yy}
    \xdef#1{#1} \xdef#2{#2}
  };
}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (3,4);
  \begin{scope}[shift={(1,1)}]
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (2,3) ;
    \coordinate (C) at ($(A)!.5!(B)$);
    \fill[red] (A) circle(2pt);
    \fill[red] (B) circle(2pt);
    \fill[blue] (C) circle(2pt);
    \extractcoord\x\y{C}
  \end{scope}
  \extractcoord\xb\yb{C}
\end{tikzpicture}

Inner scope: $(\x,\y)$\par
Global scope: $(\xb,\yb)$\par
Inner scope (fixed precision):
$(\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=2]{\x},\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=2]{\y})$\par
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Dividing a dimension by `1cm` and transforming the result into a scalar will give you the dimension's numeric value in centimetres. Combining this with TikZ's `\let` construct for coordinates (which requires the loading of TikZ's `calc` library), your example can be simplified as follows.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [help lines] (0,0) grid [step=1] (2,4);
    \draw [name path=A] (0,0) -- (2,4);
    \draw [name path=B] (2,0) -- (0,4);
    \draw [name intersections={of=A and B}]
        let
           \p1=(intersection-1),
           \n1={scalar(\x1/1cm)},
           \n2={scalar(\y1/1cm)}
        in
        (\p1)
        node [right] {(\n1,\n2)}
        circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Getting the numeric values of a coordinate's components]

---

The code above doesn't format the printed numbers explicitly. Here's a version with formatting.

The following command, `\scalar`, takes as mandatory argument a mathematical expression of the kind that can be processed by `\pgfmathparse` (of the `pgfmath` package), and strips away its dimension, if any, returning a pure numeric value. It then formats this value using `\pgfmathprintnumber` (of the `pgf` package), setting its options to `\scalar`'s optional argument.

```
\newcommand{\scalar}[2][]{%
   \pgfmathscalar{#2}%
   \pgfmathprintnumber[#1]{\pgfmathresult}%
}
```

For example, the following command, whose name `\logv` is an abbreviation of "logical value", the expression appearing in the title of your post, accepts a dimension, and returns its numeric value in centimeters (TikZ's default unit) rounded to 2 decimal places.

```
\newcommand{\logv}[1]{\scalar[precision=2,fixed zerofill]{#1/1cm}}
```

Using these tools, and keeping in mind that the `tikz` package loads both the `pgf` and the `pgfmath` packages automatically, my answer above can be rewritten as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\newcommand{\scalar}[2][]{%
   \pgfmathscalar{#2}%
   \pgfmathprintnumber[#1]{\pgfmathresult}%
}
\newcommand{\logv}[1]{\scalar[precision=2,fixed zerofill]{#1/1cm}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [help lines] (0,0) grid [step=1] (2,4);
    \draw [name path=A] (0,0) -- (2,4);
    \draw [name path=B] (2,0) -- (0,4);
    \draw [name intersections={of=A and B}]
       let \p1=(intersection-1) in
       (\p1)
       node [right] {(\logv{\x1},\logv{\y1})}
        circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Adding number formatting to the original answer]