# PGF is extracting wrong x/y values from a coordinate. How can I extract correct values?

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

Consider this MEW,

```tex
\nonstopmode
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}                                       
    \draw [gray!10](-0.2, -0.2) grid[step=.25] (3.2,3.2) ;
    \draw [gray!25](-0.2, -0.2) grid[step=.5]  (3.2,3.2) ;
    \path
        (0, 3) node[left]  {$y$}
        (3, 0) node[below] {$x$} ;

    \draw [-latex](-.2, 0) -- (3,0);
    \draw [-latex](0, -.2) -- (0,3);
                                                          
    \draw [thick, cyan!50!black, -latex]
    (0,0)    node [coordinate](origin){}
    -- 
    (60:2.5) node [coordinate](pa){}
             node [above, black]{$p_a$}
    (origin)
    --
    (30:2.5) node [coordinate](pb){}
             node [above, black]{$p_b$};

    \newdimen\pax
    \newdimen\pay
    \pgfextractx{\pax}{(pa)}
    \pgfextracty{\pay}{(pa)}
    \draw [yellow!75!black](pa) -- (\pax, 0);
    \draw [yellow!75!black](pa) -- (0, \pay);
    \draw [magenta](pb) -- (\pax, 0);
    \draw [magenta](pb) -- (0, \pay);
\end{tikzpicture}                                         
\end{document}
```

which produces this picture below:

[image: pictures]

At `\pgfextractx{\pax}{(pa)}`, I am trying to extract the x component of the node coordinate `(pa)` (same with y component), and trying to draw perpendicular with yellow lines to their respective axes. But `pgfextractx` is giving me the x/y component of node coordinate `(pb)`, which I have drawn with the magenta lines.

How can I extract the correct x/y values from the node coordinate `(pa)` with `\pgfextractx`?
I only looked at `pgfmanual.pdf` which doesn give a lot of examples of `\pgfextracttx`.

Comment: Please extend your example to a full minimal document others can copy and test as is.

Comment: Replace `\pgfextractx{\pax}{(pa)}` with `\pgfextractx{\pax}{\pgfpointanchor{pa}{center}}`. You are not in the frontend layer here, so you cannot use the parentheses syntax.

Comment: Note that `\pgfextractx` does not do wht you think it does, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/273746/3929 for an alternative. A `point` in this context is probably a low level pgf point not something named as `(pa)`. I'm guessing you're getting something like this in your log: `Missing character: There is no ( in font nullfont!` which is an indicator that something is wrong.

Comment: @daleif Yes, I was wondering what that `Missing character` error was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are in the basic layer of PGF which does not parse the syntax like the frontend layer (aka Ti*k*Z) does. In particular, the syntax using parentheses to denote a coordinate does not work here. Therefore, you need to use `\pgfpointanchor{pa}{center}` instead of `(pa)`:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newdimen\pax 
\newdimen\pay 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \draw[gray!10] (-0.2,-0.2) grid[step=.25] (3.2,3.2);
    \draw[gray!25] (-0.2,-0.2) grid[step=.5] (3.2,3.2);
    \path 
        (0,3) node[left] {$y$} 
        (3,0) node[below] {$x$} ; 
    
    \draw[-latex] (-.2,0) -- (3,0); 
    \draw[-latex] (0,-.2) -- (0,3); 
    
    \draw[thick, cyan!50!black, -latex] 
        (0,0) node[coordinate] (origin) {} 
        -- 
        (60:2.5) node[coordinate] (pa) {} 
            node[above, black] {$p_a$} 
        (origin) 
        -- 
        (30:2.5) node[coordinate] (pb) {} 
            node[above, black] {$p_b$}; 

    \pgfextractx{\pax}{\pgfpointanchor{pa}{center}} 
    \pgfextracty{\pay}{\pgfpointanchor{pa}{center}} 
    \draw[yellow!75!black] (pa) -- (\pax,0); 
    \draw[yellow!75!black] (pa) -- (0,\pay); 
    \draw[magenta] (pb) -- (\pax,0); 
    \draw[magenta] (pb) -- (0,\pay);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1, but, please, move `\newdimen` outside the `tikzpicture` (best is in the preamble). In a `standalone` document this makes no difference, but in a standard document with several similar pictures it would.

Comment: @egreg why? A `\newdimen` in one `tikzpicture` environment leaks into another?

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the notice!

Comment: @sigsegv `\newdimen` permanently allocates a register. So in case of multiple such calls inside `tikzpicture` you waste two registers per call. Not a big deal, because there are more than 32000 registers available, but it's conceptually wrong.