# Using font-relative distances in tikzpictures

Tags: tikz-pgf

When I use `scale` in tikzpictures (without `transform shape`), the text size in nodes is not changed (which is good and well). Suppose now that I want to put some node in a scaled graph using a distance proportional to the node font; I naively supposed that I could use `ex` coords, but see below...

I also printed the values of the coordinates, and [`\pgf@yy` which should give the unit vector](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18292/accessing-the-logic-values-of-a-tikz-coordinate), but there is something I miss here...

Is there a way to express a distance which is proportional to the (default) font size, independently from the scale?

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newdimen\mydimA\newdimen\mydimB
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\showat}[1]{%
    \pgfextracty\mydimA{\pgfpointanchor{A}{center}}
    \pgfextracty\mydimB{\pgfpointanchor{B}{center}}
    \node[red, font=\tiny,  align=left] at(#1) {Before \the\mydimA \\ After \the\mydimB \\
    Scale y \the\pgf@yy};
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \draw (0,0)  --(1,0) coordinate(A) -- (2,0);
    \path (A) ++(0,1ex) coordinate(B);
    \node [anchor=base] at (B) {$R_g$};
    \showat{1,-1}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline, scale=2]
    \draw (0,0)  --(0.5,0) coordinate(A) -- (1,0);
    \path (A) ++(0,1ex) coordinate(B);
    \node [anchor=base] at (B) {$R_g$};
    \showat{0.5,-0.5}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline, scale=0.01]
    \draw (0,0)  --(100,0) coordinate(A) -- (200,0);
    \path (A) ++(0,1ex) coordinate(B);
    \node [anchor=base] at (B) {$R_g$};
    \showat{100,-100}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you want to scale the whole picture you could use \resizebox -- which scales everything (line width, text spacing)

Comment: @AubreyBlumsohn, no, it's not a matter of rescaling the whole picture. I want to be able to say that a label should be at 1ex distance from an anchor, no matter the scale of the figure... it's for a much more complex case, really (see https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues/91) .

Comment: I didn't understand your question.

Comment: Coordinates are transformed by scaling while node text isn't. I'm not sure why one would expect something else. Internally, TeX does not care if it is `cm` or `ex`, it's all `sp`.

Comment: @AndréC Basically the question is how to get all these three tikzpictures to produce the same results while using coordinate transformations based on font dimensions like `ex` (relative to the node font).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `1em` is being converted at read time into the coordinate system, which is then affected by the picture scale. You can use `reset cm` to locally reset the coordinate transformation matrix, locally cancelling the picture scale effect.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \draw (0,0)  --(1,0) coordinate(A) -- (2,0);
    \path (A) ++(0,1em) coordinate(B);
    \node [anchor=base] at (B) {$R_g$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline, scale=2]
  \draw (0,0)  --(0.5,0) coordinate(A) -- (1,0);
  \path[reset cm] (A) ++(0,1em) coordinate(B);
  \node [anchor=base] at (B) {$R_g$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline, scale=0.01]
  \draw (0,0)  --(100,0) coordinate(A) -- (200,0);
  \path[reset cm] (A) ++(0,1em) coordinate(B);
  \node [anchor=base] at (B) {$R_g$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I used this and it works as supposed... thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Resetting the scale locally is one option (see Marsden's answer), but there is a better way to go about things.

With `scale=factor`, *all* coordinates are scaled by `factor`, regardless of their dimension (while the unit vectors are unchanged, as you discovered). Instead, redefine the length of the unit vectors according to the desired scaling. For example, with `y={(0cm,2cm)}`, while `(0,0) -- (1,0)` will be twice the usual distance, coordinates with dimensions, such as `(0,1ex)`, will be unchanged:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \draw (0,0)  --(1,0) coordinate(A) -- (2,0);
    \path (A) ++(0,1ex) coordinate(B);
    \node [anchor=base] at (B) {$R_g$};
    \showat{1,-1cm}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline, x={(2cm,0cm)},y={(0cm,2cm)}]
    % Identical code to previous picture:
    \draw (0,0)  --(1,0) coordinate(A) -- (2,0);
    \path[scale=1] (A) ++(0,1ex) coordinate(B);
    \node [anchor=base] at (B) {$R_g$};
    \showat{1,-1cm}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: output]

Note how the distance between `A` and `B` is unchanged, while `\the\pgf@yy` has doubled, as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you place B as itself a node *(with relative placement)*?

That would solve all your problems.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newdimen\mydimA\newdimen\mydimB
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\showat}[1]{%
    \pgfextracty\mydimA{\pgfpointanchor{A}{center}}
    \pgfextracty\mydimB{\pgfpointanchor{B}{center}}
    \node[red, font=\tiny,  align=left] at(#1) {Before \the\mydimA \\ After \the\mydimB \\
    Scale y \the\pgf@yy};
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tikzset{node distance=1ex}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \draw (0,0)  --(1,0) coordinate(A) -- (2,0);
    \node[above=of A,anchor=base](B){$R_g$};
    \showat{1,-1}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline, scale=2]
    \draw (0,0)  --(0.5,0) coordinate(A) -- (1,0);
    %\path (A) ++(0,1ex) coordinate(B)node{y};
    \node[above=of A,anchor=base] (B) {$R_g$};
    \showat{0.5,-0.5}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline, scale=0.01]
    \draw (0,0)  --(100,0) coordinate(A) -- (200,0);
    %\path (A) ++(0,1ex) coordinate(B)node{y};
    \node[above=of A,anchor=base] (B) {$R_g$};
    \showat{100,-100}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

[Eric Marsden's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/29621/eric-marsden) explains nicely what's going on. However, I would just read out the relevant entry of the transformation matrix (it is the 22 entry) and "invert" it. This is a trick that I also used (without inversion, of course) to scale the line width with a shape because by default it doesn't scale.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newdimen\mydimA\newdimen\mydimB
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\showat}[1]{%
    \pgfextracty\mydimA{\pgfpointanchor{A}{center}}
    \pgfextracty\mydimB{\pgfpointanchor{B}{center}}
    \node[red, font=\tiny,  align=left] at(#1) {Before \the\mydimA \\ After \the\mydimB \\
    Scale y \the\pgf@yy};
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \draw (0,0)  --(1,0) coordinate(A) -- (2,0);
    \pgfgettransformentries{\tmp}{\tmp}{\tmp}{\myscale}{\tmp}{\tmp}
    \path  (A) ++(0,1ex/\myscale) coordinate(B);
    \node [anchor=base] at (B) {$R_g$};
    \showat{1,-1}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline, scale=2]
    \draw (0,0)  --(0.5,0) coordinate(A) -- (1,0);
    \pgfgettransformentries{\tmp}{\tmp}{\tmp}{\myscale}{\tmp}{\tmp}
    \path  (A) ++(0,1ex/\myscale) coordinate(B);
    \node [anchor=base] at (B) {$R_g$};
    \showat{0.5,-0.5}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline, scale=0.01]
    \draw (0,0)  --(100,0) coordinate(A) -- (200,0);
    \pgfgettransformentries{\tmp}{\tmp}{\tmp}{\myscale}{\tmp}{\tmp}
    \path  (A) ++(0,1ex/\myscale) coordinate(B);
    \node [anchor=base] at (B) {$R_g$};
    \showat{100,-100}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @marmot, +1! I already accepted Eric's answer (and implemented it), but I think both are valid.

Comment: @Rmano Yes, Eric was the first to point out what the problem is and provided an elegant way to fix it. You should definitely accept his nice answer.